# Why is c++ std::forward always return right value without template

Tags: c++, reference, universal, perfect-forwarding

I am trying to understand c++ perfect forwarding, and I do experiments with the following code:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void inner(int&) {cout << "left" << endl;}
void inner(int&&) {cout << "right" << endl;}

template<typename T>
void outer_templ(T&& t) {
    inner(std::forward<T>(t));
}

void outer(int& t) {
    inner(std::forward<int>(t));
}

void outer(int&& t) {
    inner(std::forward<int>(t));

}



int main() {
    int aa = 10;
    outer(aa);
    outer(10);
    outer_templ(aa);
    outer_templ(10);

    return 0;
}
```

And the result is:

```
right
right
left 
right
```

Does this mean that std::forward must be used together with template, or to be specific, std::forwarding must be used with universal reference?

Comment: The first `inner(std::forward<int>(t))` should be `inner(std::forward<int&>(t))` if you want to get the behavior of a forwarding reference. Please use a single question in one post.

Comment: When you pass an lvalue to `outer_templ`, `T` gets deduced to `int &`, so as 273K said, that's what the first version of `outer` should pass to `std::forward` to correctly imitate `outer_templ`.

Comment: @273K Thanks , I will open a new post, and modify this to remove the second question.

Comment: What would be the point of using it in a context where you know the type?

Comment: You use `std::forward` to capture what T has been deduced as. In the second and third case you alredy know the types, and can use `t` and `std::move(t)` instead.